# For rails app, to push to Heroku, I have modified the gemfile, do I need to modify it back for locally testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gemfile

Since now I would like to add something new to the rails app, so I have to re-modify the code and test locally on my computer. Do I need to modify the gemfile back?

The current gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
...
```

Comment: If you mean by "modify the gemfile back" to remove the section in "group :production" then no, you do not have to. The whole point of putting those in the production group mean they only apply to production so it does not effect your local devleopment and test environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you dont have so.

I assume you have added gem `rails_12factor` in production group